# Why is frontend of Magento site not loading up? - Fatal error: Class ‘Mage__Helper_Data’ not found

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error

I’ve got an issue with the front end of a magento site, it is throwing a 500 error. The back end admin is absolutely fine and functional, I'm able to log in no problem and there is no loss of product data.

I have un-commented out line 70 in my index.php file -

```
#ini_set(\'display_errors\', 1);
```

in order to see the errors, and this is what now displays when you load up the front end of the site - **Fatal error: Class \’Mage__Helper_Data\’ not found in /var/www/vhosts/beta.mydomain.com/httpdocs/countrytoys/app/Mage.php on line 520**

I reckon the double underscore here is to do with a module being missing or something..

This problem came to light after I refreshed all cache types in the admin area, but I suspect the problem was there beforehand but just bared it’s head after the cache refresh.

**So far I have tried/checked -**

- deleting the contents of var/cache, var/session
- The base URL in the db is correct
- made all directories 755 permissions, and all files 644, I have also tried making index.php 755, and 777 on suggestion from other forums.
- checked htaccess, all seems fine.
- the physical files are all there on the server.
- system.log seems to be consistently pointing to line 93 in Autoload.php -

  ```
  2011-09-12T15:18:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href=\'function.include\'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening \'Mage//Helper/Data.php\' for inclusion (include_path=\'/var/www/vhosts/beta.mydomain.com/httpdocs/countrytoys/app/code/local:/var/www/vhosts/beta.mydomain.com/httpdocs/countrytoys/app/code/community:/var/www/vhosts/beta.mydomain.com/httpdocs/countrytoys/app/code/core:/var/www/vhosts/beta.mydomain.com/httpdocs/countrytoys/lib:.:\')  in /var/www/vhosts/beta.mydomain.com/httpdocs/countrytoys/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
  ```

Other things I can think of that I have recently done include adding google analytics through admin, altering the code for links at the top of the site in app\design\frontend\default\blue_toys\template\page\html\header.phtml and entering some paypal details in order to set up the payment gateway.

installation details -
ver -1.5.0.1,
Theme - custom installed theme

Can anyone help?
thanks,
Luke

Comment: and does the file exist?

Comment: I presume you're referring to Data.php, as displayed in the log? in which case, the path - Mage//Helper/Data.php has missing a directory, what's up with that? so, no I don't think the file exists.

Comment: grep from codebase for "Mage__Helper_Data" and see which file has the typo for double dash "__"

Comment: thanks, tried that, but it returned 0 results, could this be generated on the fly or something?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? And do you have any third party modules installed?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's efforts on this, I have since abandoned this site and started it from scratch and all appears fine now, (so far!)

Answer (score 0):

Your error message shows *two* underscores between `Mage` and `Helper`, where there usually is only *one* of them. For me it looks like you lost a word between `Mage` and `Helper` somewhere, as usually Mage helper identifiers are s/t like `Mage_Core_Helper_Data`.

I'd check the `<helpers>` sections of my `/etc/config.xml` files for wrong definitions first.

Other than that I'd probably try to get a debug trace inside the `Varien_Autoload::autoload` method.

I'd lookout for patterns in the parameter `$class` which could result in s/t like `Mage__Helper_Data`, e.g. occurences where `$class` contains spaces or double underscores:

```
public function autoload($class)
{

    try {
        if (strpos($class, ' ') !== false || strpos($class, '__') !== false) {
            throw new Exception('fishy');
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($class, $e->getTraceAsString());
        die('stop');
    }

    // original method code starts here
    // :

}
```

Comment: There isn't a <helpers> section in my app/etc/config.xml file for some reason, is this something I should add in?

Comment: No, they are located under each module folder in the etc/config.xml.

Comment: ok, are you saying each module folder should have a config.xml file?

Comment: @LukeKM7: yes, usually each module does have its own `app/code/<codepool>/<company>/<module>/etc/config.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks Jurgen, Janus. I have checked each config.xml file for anything missing within the <helpers> sections, nothing abnormal, no missing words or anything. Not sure where to go with this really. any more ideas?

Comment: @LukeKM7: try getting a trace and post it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and this question appeared in the Google results, so I thought it would be sensible to add an answer here for anyone else struggling with the same problem. With my issue, it was related to a custom `<source_model>` I was trying to use in the Magento configuration system.

I used the example code from Magento, which looks like this:

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 0, 'label' => Mage::helper()->__('First item')),
            array('value' => 1, 'label' => Mage::helper()->__('Second item')),
            array('value' => 2, 'label' => Mage::helper()->__('third item'))
        );
    }
```

The error was coming from the `Mage::helper()` bit - no helper was being loaded. You can change it to this, or load a specific helper:

```
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 0, 'label' => 'First item'),
            array('value' => 1, 'label' => 'Second item'),
            array('value' => 2, 'label' => 'third item')
        );
    }
```